# Flutter - How to make a Material Button stationery while scrolling page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, arabic, singlechildscrollview, materialbutton

[image]
ADDED PICTURE:
Edited: June23, 2020
for clarification... I. need these two buttons to not move at all and stay at the same position,  when I scroll these buttons are stationary but as the page scrolls  the movement of the page moves the buttons so meaning it won't be on line 1 any more if I scroll to line 4 first button is on line 4 and second button is on line 5. I don't want them to move at all... I

Basically, since I need to make the image do a command I need to add a button and code in order for it to do it or its just a png image.

need to add many buttons over the text within the picture ...How can I achieve this ..? I tried different tactics but as the scroll moves the buttons move too ..

I am creating  an APP which has a lot of emphasis on the image in the background as such, their is text in arabic on that image per line and I want to add "material buttons" on top of this text. I was able to do this ... but then I used single child scroll which I only want the image to scroll but not the buttons. I want the buttons to stay in one specific position and not scroll , since the logic is on swiping right -- user will see the invisible material button become active and show English text for that specific position on swiping left user will see the arabic text that is on the image ....

please help

EDITED THE CODE TO ONLY SHOW THE ISSUE AND GOT RID OF COMMENTED CODE to show just one stack. -

LAYOUT USED:
Stack and laid out Image with single scroll and closed it off
and after that added the Raised button,

Layout needed:
Just want the single child scroll to scroll the image not the raised buttons that are on top of the image. I want those buttons to be stationary ....  Maybe its a positional problem, I need to add the a different type of scroll ?

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:Quran_highlighter/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:system_shortcuts/system_shortcuts.dart';
import 'package:Quran_highlighter/Widgets/NavDrawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:zoom_widget/zoom_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

class Aliflaammeem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AliflaammeemState createState() => _AliflaammeemState();
}

class _AliflaammeemState extends State<Aliflaammeem> {

  changeTextEnglish() {
    setState(() {
      bool _visible = true;
         _visible =  _visible;
      textHolder = "All Praise and Thanks is to Allah the lord of the worlds";
    });
  }

  changeTextArabic() {
    bool _visible = true;
    setState(() {
      _visible =  _visible;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



   SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
        Center(child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: SafeArea(
              top: true,
              bottom: true,
              right: true,
              left: true,
              child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage('test/assets/quranpg0.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
              // ),
          // ),
        // ),
        // ),
                  // ),      
        // Container(
        //      child:Align(
        //        alignment: Alignment(.00,-.7
        //        ),
        //     // color: Colors.red,
        //     child: FloatingActionButton(
        //         // color: Colors.red,
        //         elevation: 9,
        //         onPressed: () => 0,
        //         child: Text("Static "))
                
        //    ),
        // ),   
              
           Container(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(.00, -.8
            ),
          child: _visible
              ? MaterialButton(
              height: 70.0,
              // minWidth: 36.5,
              // minWidth: 85.0,
              minWidth: 100.0,
              onPressed: () => changeTextArabic1(),
              onLongPress: () => changeTextEnglish1(),
              // child: Text(labels[i]),
              child: Text(surah0),
              // color: Colors.cyan[400],
              color: Colors.purple[300],
              highlightColor: Colors.blue,
              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(60.0)
              ),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, top: 2, right: 78, bottom: 5),
              )
              :Container(),
              
            ),
            ),
          Container(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(.00, -.35
            ),
          child: _visible
              ? MaterialButton(
              height: 70.0,
              // minWidth: 36.5,
              // minWidth: 85.0,
              minWidth: 100.0,
              onPressed: () => changeTextArabic1(),
              onLongPress: () => changeTextEnglish1(),
              // child: Text(labels[i]),
              child: Text(label0),
              color: Colors.cyan[400],
              // color: Colors.purple[300],
              highlightColor: Colors.blue,
              // shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(60.0)
              // ),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: -4, top: 2, right: -4, bottom: 5),
              )
              :Container(),
              
            ),
            ),
        Container(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(.00, 0.1
            ),
          child: _visible
              ? MaterialButton(
              height: 70.0,
              // minWidth: 36.5,
              // minWidth: 85.0,
              minWidth: 100.0,
              onPressed: () => changeTextArabic1(),
              onLongPress: () => changeTextEnglish1(),
              // child: Text(labels[i]),
              child: Text(label1),
              color: Colors.cyan[400],
              // color: Colors.purple[300],
              highlightColor: Colors.blue,
              // shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(60.0)
              // ),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 2, right: 33, bottom: 5),
              )
              :Container(),
              
            ),
            ),
            // for(int i = 0; i< labels.length; i++)
               Container(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(.00, 0.54
            ),
      child: _visible
      ?
            MaterialButton(
              height: 70.0,
              minWidth: 100,
              onPressed: () => changeTextArabic1(),
              onLongPress: () => changeTextEnglish1(),
              // Positioned(
              // top: 21,
              child: Text(label2),
              disabledTextColor: Colors.transparent,
              color: Colors.cyan[300],
              // color: Colors.purple[300],
              highlightColor: Colors.blue,
              // shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(60.0)
              // ),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 90, top: 0, right: 100, bottom: 5),
          )
          :Container()
          ),
        ),
                     Container(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(.00, .99
            ),
      child: _visible
      ?
            MaterialButton(
              height: 70.0,
              minWidth: 100,
              onPressed: () => changeTextArabic1(),
              onLongPress: () => changeTextEnglish1(),
              // Positioned(
              // top: 21,
              child: Text(label3),
              disabledTextColor: Colors.transparent,
              color: Colors.cyan[300],
              // color: Colors.purple[300],
              highlightColor: Colors.blue,
              // shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(60.0)
              // ),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 120, top: 2, right: 118, bottom: 5),
          )
          :Container()
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
        if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
          print("right swipe english");
          changeTextEnglish1();
          setState(() {
 
          });
        } else if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
          print("left swipe arabic");
          changeTextArabic1();
          setState(() {
          });
        }
    }
    )))))]));}}
```

Comment: Please post minimal code, the one that doesn't contain useless commented blocks for example. And also show the layout that you have vs the layout that you want to achieve to better understand the situation.

Comment: How about using a Floating Action Button?

Comment: I edited the code based on your feedback...please review and help me... I can't do floating action button because I would need probably 4-8 floating action buttons...to be stationary on top of the image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATE:

After some research I've concluded that you can use floatingActionButton and floatingActionButtonLocation to position a floatingActionButton that will not be affected by scrolling. You could also use Center of Align to position it where you want.

**I hope this works for you!**

## Original post:

I think the easiest and most efficient way would be to use a raisedButton passed in buttomNavigationBar. I've seen people using a CustomScrollView but the button kind of stutters when doing that. buttonNavigationBar seems to be the best way to go. You can use color and elevation to blend in with your background.

Don't forget to flag this as an answer if it was any help!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final text = "echo\n" * 1000;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Static button"),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(child: Text(text)),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.white,
                elevation: 0,
                onPressed: () => 0,
                child: Text("Static Button"))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The thing is I need the buttons on the center and in specific coordinates of the page

Comment: for example -  Container(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(.27, 0.1
            ),
          //   child: Visibility(
          // visible: _visible,
          // maintainSize: true,
          // maintainAnimation: true,
          // maintainState: true,
              child: MaterialButton(
              height: 70.0,
              // minWidth: 36.5,
              minWidth: 85.0,

Comment: I think you could make it work with a CustomScrollView the results wouldn't be as good, I'll do some digging and get back at you.

Comment: I tried this code with both raised button and floating action button and both were still scrolling as the page would scroll ......

Comment: Could you send a recording of this? It seemed to work fine on my computer.

Comment: 1. The code you specified has the static raised button on the bottom which I  don't need it at the bottom I need a button to be positioned at specific x and y coordinates throughout the page on top of the image .... 2. for floating button tried that as well and only  4 specific locations I can place this ....FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked : sticked to buttom center.
FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat : float at center of the bottom.
FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked : sticked to buttom center.
FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat : float at bottom center.

Comment: I'm afraid I've ran out of advice. Good day to you !

Answer (score 0):

I think you had to many Stack.
I just removed a few and made this working example.
Hope it's what you wanted.

```
class Aliflaammeem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AliflaammeemState createState() => _AliflaammeemState();
}

class _AliflaammeemState extends State<Aliflaammeem> {
  var nameList = new List<String>();
  final items = List<String>.generate(20, (i) => "Item ${i + 1}");

  List<MaterialButton> buttonsList = new List<MaterialButton>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    nameList.add("I love");
    nameList.add("my ALLAH");
    nameList.add("SWT Very Much");
  }

  List<String> labels = ['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'kiwi'];
  bool _visible = true;
  int _counter = 0;
  double _initial = 0.0;

  var textHolder = "";

  changeTextEnglish() {
    setState(() {
      _visible = true;
      textHolder = "All Praise and Thanks is to Allah the lord of the worlds";
    });
  }

  changeTextArabic() {
    setState(() {
      _visible = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Dismissing Items';
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: <Widget>[
      SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 300,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 300,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              height: 300,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              height: 300,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment(.27, 0.1),
          child: _visible
              ? MaterialButton(
                  height: 70.0,
                  minWidth: 85.0,
                  onPressed: () => changeTextArabic(),
                  onLongPress: () => changeTextEnglish(),
                  child: Text('$textHolder'),
                  color: Colors.cyan[400],
                  highlightColor: Colors.blue,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 2, right: -1, bottom: 5),
                )
              : Container(),
        ),
      ),
      for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
        Container(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(-.5, 0.1),
            child: MaterialButton(
              height: 70.0,
              minWidth: 36.5,
              onPressed: () => changeTextArabic(),
              onLongPress: () => changeTextEnglish(),
              child: Text(labels[i]),
              disabledTextColor: Colors.transparent,
              color: Colors.cyan[300],
              highlightColor: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 46, top: 2, right: -20, bottom: 5),
            ),
//  ),
          ),
        ),
      GestureDetector(onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
        if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
          print("right swipe english");
          changeTextEnglish();
          setState(() {});
        } else if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
          print("left swipe arabic");
          changeTextArabic();
          setState(() {});
        }
      })
    ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code out, but 1. the image is the most important thing and I want the button or container on the image and I don't want it to move while scrolling - I added text as the child and added the image I could see the text on top of the image with the color but when I scroll it the container with text is moving too ...  ),
            Container(
              child: Text("hey what is up"),
              color: Colors.green,
              height: 50,

Comment: @shahbaz if you want to add a button add it to the stack not the SingleChildScrollView. And if you don't want it to move you should use a positionned widget. Juste add your text like so (put it just before the gesture detector):
      Positioned(
        height: 50,
        child: Container(
          child: Text("hey what is up"),
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),

Comment: Hi Lucas, I did try your code and added the button right before the gesture detector but am getting the same issueStack(children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
              top: 180,
              bottom: 170,
              left:280,
          
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(.2, -.100,
            ),
        
              // right:2 ,
              // height:.0 ,
              // width: 36.5,    
        child: MaterialButton(
              // height: 70.0,
              // minWidth: 36.5,
              onPressed: () => changeTextArabic1()

Comment: Did you try my code with no changes ? Is it not what you wanted to achieve ? If not please explain to me what you what that I did not do

Comment: Hi Lucas, I did try your code multiple times and I did tweak it also but I am still seeing all the buttons move when I add a material button into your code, its still moves with the single scroll I need for some way for the buttons to remain stationary once I scroll the page ... how can I achieve this I have updated my code with one stack please if you could help ....